# Owl Carousel "is-transitioned" class only added from second image after initialized but work after the loop on first image

Tags: jquery

The use of a code to do transitioned text for each image of my owl-carousel doesn't fully work with my website. The class "is-transitioned" is added only from the second image when the page is loaded but is added after the loop on the first image. For the test I'm using the same text for each image.

the source code work fine : https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/oPeLJR

I suppose that the problem come with :

```
const $currentOwlItem = $(".owl-item").eq(e.item.index);
  $currentOwlItem.find(".owl-slide-animated").addClass("is-transitioned");
```

or perhaps it depends if jquery is loading "onload" or "ready". 
But in two cases, it doesn't change anything.

I have no error in browser. the code works fine only from the second image and after the loop on all images.
My jQuery file using owl-carousel is called "anim.js"

Answer (score 0):

my problem has been resolved :
I have put my owlCarousel (first) jQuery code just after $(document).ready(
I have let the second owlCarousel at the end of my jQuery Code.